# Is there an easy way to allow incoming traffic from the AWS Console (in web-browser) in network security settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

Is there a single rule that would work well, or a formulaic security protocol rule?

I've tried allowing ssh access from my network, but the problem is I can't get into the instance and add my public key to the list of known hosts. I tried launching the EC2 instance with my specific key pair, but I still get `permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Check the Security Group allows SSH over port 22, make sure you have the correct PEM file, you can only get to save it once (see KeyPairs in the Console under EC2's). Also clarify what OS it is Linux or Windows and what OS are you using?

Comment: That error suggests you can make a network connection to the box, but the authentication is failing.  I'd verify you have the right key and username.